# Homology of a vector space modulo a finite group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, quotient-spaces, group-cohomology

I'm looking at a proof concerning homology of graph complexes.
One has a chain complex $(V, \partial)$ of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces
$$\cdots \xrightarrow{\partial}V_n \xrightarrow{\partial} V_{n-1} \xrightarrow{\partial} \cdots$$
There is a finite group $G$ acting on all of these spaces $V_n$, so that we may consider the quotient spaces $V_n/G$ and the corresponding chain complex $(V/G, \partial)$.
Now in the proof it says: "over the rationals, finite groups have no homology, a fact which implies that the chain complexes $(V, \partial)$ and $(V/G, \partial)$ are rationally quasi-isomorphic."

I don't understand the following things in this statement:

**What does it mean for a group to have no homology (what does one even mean by the "homology of a group")?**

**Why do finite groups have no homology over the rationals?**

**Why does $G$ having no homology imply that the two chain complexes are quasi-isomorphic?**

For the third question, I would think that one can do something with the long exact sequence in homology. So, if one would have a short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow G \rightarrow V \rightarrow V/G \rightarrow 0$$
then the long exact sequence in homology and the fact that $G$ has no homology would imply the quasi-isomorphicness. But the first map in the above short exact sequence doesn't really make sense...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Would you have the reference for the article you're reading?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It's the proof of Lemma 2.1 in the paper "Cut vertices in commutative graphs" (arXiv:math/0307364 )

Comment: Well if I'm being honest I don't understand their argument. I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 2):

[Group homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology) is a construction that takes a topological group $G$ and outputs a vector space (assuming you're working over some base field). There are several equivalent definitions; one of them is that it is given by $H^*(BG; \Bbbk)$ where $BG$ is the  [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) of $G$.

It is a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Higher_cohomology_groups_are_torsion) that if $G$ is a finite group, then $H^n(G; \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$; this is what is meant by the informal sentence "over the rationals, a finite group has no cohomology".

Now this is where it gets technical. There is the *Cartan–Leray spectral sequence*, a [spectral sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_sequence) with $E^2$ page
$$E^2_pq = H_p(G; H_q(V))$$
and converging to $H_*(V/G)$, when $G$ acts freely on $V$. Over the rationals higher group homology is trivial, so we have
$$H_p(G; H_q(V)) = \begin{cases} H_q(V)/G, & \text{if } p = 0; \\ 0, & \text{if } p > 0. \end{cases}$$
So the $E^2$ page is concentrated on the first column, so the sequence collapses and thus $H_*(V)/G$ is isomorphic (still over $\mathbb{Q})$ to $H_*(V/G)$ as a graded vector space.

Now this isn't quite what you've written, but maybe with the precise reference there are more hypotheses on how $G$ acts on $V$ to get the result.

As it is the result as stated can't be true in such generality, take for example $V = \mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$ concentrated in degree $0$ with zero differential and $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acting by swapping the two factors. Then $V/G \cong \mathbb{Q}$ concentrated in degree zero: $V$ and $V/G$ don't even have the same homology, so they cannot possibly be quasi-isomorphic. (However we do have $H_*(V/G) \cong H_*(V)/G$, which agrees with what I've written above.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! In my case, $G$ is the automorphism group of a graph, which I think indeed acts freely on the considered vector space $V$. So is the freeness of the group action a sufficient condition for the statement $H_*(V)/G \cong H_*(V/G)$?

Comment: @TomBombadil It is I think, yes.

Comment: Although your answer explains a lot, unfortunately the isomorphism $H_*(V)/G \cong H_*(V/G)$ isn't quite enough yet for my case...

Comment: I noticed that in my case this isomorphism actually is enough, since $V/G$ has zero homology. So it follows from $0  = H(V/G) = H(V)/G$ that also $H(V) = 0$ since $H(V)$ is a vector space. Moreover, the isomorphism $H(V/G) = H(V)/G$ can be proven much easier since $G$ is finite, namely by noting that invariants and co-invariants are isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and using a decomposition $V = V^G \oplus W$ which results from an idempotent map $\pi: V \rightarrow V$. Taking homology and looking at $G$-invariants, one finds that it is enough to show $H(W)^G = 0$, which is very simple.